# Storing two tokens in Android AccountManager

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-account

I work with an API that, when logging in, provides two types of tokens that are both needed. 
The Android `AccountManager` stores only one auth token, how could I save the second one? 
Saving one token with the `AccountManager` and implementing some own storage logic for the other token would kind of render the whole use of `AccountManager` useless.

I thought of combining the two tokens to one `String`, seperated by some special `char`, then saving that `String` to the `AccountManager`.

Any better / more elegant ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get your question.

If you want to *store* two kinds of tokens nicely, you can just use different suffix of token keys when saving tokens to AccountManager.

If you want to provide two tokens at the same time for AccountManager's getAuthToken() API, there could be several ways to do it. One way is the way you've described, that returns two tokens separated by a special char. Another way, is to ask developer to call getAuthToken() twice with different token types.